# Delphi2010-IDE keeps stoping on CPU debug window

Tags: delphi, debugging, delphi-2010, delphi-7, cpu

I keep getting the CPU-debug window in D2010 IDE, i noticed this appears on some Breakepoints, some others doesnt cause this effect. Can't explain when exactly this happends or which Breakpoints cause this but it seems like when the debugger can't reach a breackpoint on code it stops on the beginaddress of the method, and it gets in an endless loop so even removing the Breakpoint doesnt help, only solution is break debugging, remove breakpoint and restart again. I had the same issue with D7 but more often.

Can anybody explain this? is it a bug or a configuration issue? how helpfull are cpu debug info? at the moment i cant really make any use of them, can anybody recommend some tools, articles on how to use this information usfully.

Thank you.

Comment: Learn assembler if you would like to make use of CPU Debug Window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A workaround for this problem is to do a full CLEAN of your developer working folders. Delete all DCU and DCP files, and then rebuild.  This happened to me a lot in Delphi 2010, and seems to be fixed in Delphi XE

Comment: bug is still here in xe5, +1 for solution

Comment: Does it happen on your app units or on component units?  Is deleting all .identcache files enough to fix it?

Comment: can't reproduce it for now. I just run clean&build with all of my bpls and it gone. I will write more, if I stuck in it again

Answer (score 4):

This is usually caused by having debug information in DCUs (third party or Delphi's own VCL), but not having the source available on the browsing path.

Make sure you don't have "Use Debug DCUs" checked in `Project->Options-Linker`. You also may want to open the source for any third-party components you use (the packages), change them to *not* use debug information, and rebuild them as well. You can always re-compile if you find a bug in them and need to trace into the source.

One additional thing to make sure of is that you don't have the `$(BDS)\Lib\Debug` value set in the Library or Browsing paths (`Project->Options->Compiler` in D2010); this will prevent the debug DCUs from being picked up when stepping through the code. (Set it to `$(BDS)\Lib` instead.)